# Browser not updating code changes for Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm having this issue where everytime I update my code in my editor, the browser never sees the changes. I fix it by clearing the cookies and cache and restarting the http-server in cmd. How can I get it to update in realtime without having to do all these steps?

Comment: Have your console open and use the "clear cache on reload" function

Comment: use tools like grunt or gulp and watch the specific files.
-> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Comment: You probably also need to add a query string that updates on each change to force the browser not to cache the data.

Comment: `ctrl+F5` refreshes the page and clears the cache.

Comment: Agree using gulp is probably the way to go, grunt is a bit "older" (by months I think) but based on monolithic config and plugins that execute based on the config whereas gulp is written more as functions that take arguments and data is piped from one process to another (uses node a bit better IMO).  Other options are out there too WebPack is particularly pretty interesting but more on the build side than the live reload.

Answer (score 0):

Use the node module `live-server`. It will detect the changes for you and update your app in browser. There are many other tools like `browser-sync` which do much more.
I believe you can also configure your http-server to not cache your app. You can also set in your browser like chrome that whenever dev tools are open don't use cache.